# How to convert quaternions from UE4 to Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, unreal-engine4

UE4 and Unity3d has different coordinate systems. I am trying to convert quaternions from UE4 to Unity3d by simply remapping UE4 [x, y, z, w] -> Unity3d [x, z, -y, w]. But it seems that I am doing something completely wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

From https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/495437/convert-unreal-quaternion-to-unity.html :

> Rotation around ... X is now rotation around Z ... Y is now around X
>   ... Z is now around Y

So it should be Unity3d[z,x,y,w] right?

Comment: Could you provide info on why you think that? How does it seem you doing something wrong? Showing your code will help to indentify what possibly goes wrong

Comment: I simply comparing with quaternions in Unity3d (some reference values) with converted by me quaternions. Reference values are not looks like they were simply remapped.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution from `UE[x,y,z,w]` to Unity3D is `[z,-y,x,w]`.
I found this via testing.